# Did cats have magical powers in Batman Returns?

Tags: plot-explanation, batman-returns

In Tim Burton's Batman Returns, Max Shreck throws Selina out a high story window where she plunges to the ground. It's not quite clear to me if she dies upon landing or just knocking at death's door.

Regardless, cats come out of nowhere and start licking her and nipping at her fingers:

[image: Selena screen capture from Batman Returns]

Next thing you know, she's more assertive, confident and has quite the spring in her step (the back-flips and whatnot).

What role did the cats play making Catwoman?

Comment: Of course, cats always have magical powers!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The way I've always read that scene is that she fell, but did not die. She did however suffer severe trauma. The larger part of that trauma was to her psyche. An oft used story telling instrument in movies is the personality switching trauma. This happened to Selina when she fell, it changed her into a more assertive character. Having the cats around her when she woke up as the new Selina "impressed" on her mind a more feline personality. Not only is she more aggressive and independent, she also moves and acts more like a cat. You could say that the trauma to her head made her more than a little bit 'insane'.

Comment: So OP's idea is basically Selina's interpretation of events as she wakes up; but it is not truly the case, she just thinks it is? I.e. Selina (consciously or subconciously) believes that the cats have a (potentially magical) importance; while that is not true in reality (i.e. the movie's reality).

Comment: What of her "other" lives when she fights Batman, Penguin and Max Schreck later in the movie?

Comment: Indeed she does fall through several awnings which in movie land would be enough for her to survive. @m1gp0z `What of her "other" lives when she fights Batman, Penguin and Max Schreck later in the movie?` - in each case there is at least a little seed of doubt as to whether the result would necessarily be fatal ("Hee hee hee! Saved by kitty litter!")

Answer (score 7):

The [shooting script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/batman-returns_shooting.html) states that her fall was slowed by a flagpole
(in the movie it was [an awning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUH8C.png)) and she was pretty lucky in how she landed. It wasn't immediately fatal.

> Her fall is (luckily) slowed by a protruding flagpole with the smiling Shreck cat logo on its flapping flag.
> Then she (luckily) lands in a deep snowdrift.

It's possible she would have died (due to being knocked unconscious in the snow) had the cats not warmed her and awakened her.

> Miss Kitty, summoned by her desperate owner, now appears
> ... leading cats of every shape, color and demeanor from
> every direction.  Selina's cat crawls up onto Selina's
> blouse and begins to breathe into her mouth in an eerie
> feline C.P.R. ballet.
>
> A Siamese whispers in Selina's ear, aw-so-cute Tabbies
> snuggle against the soles of her feet.  A scraggly Tom
> viciously bites her finger.  Selina's eyes fly open.

---

The [novelisation](https://batman.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Returns_(Novelization)) more explicitly states that her fall was not fatal.

> She heard canvas rip as she fell through an awning. She couldn’t feel
> anything anymore. Then she hit a second awning, and a third, all the
> fronts of the fancy multistoried Gotham Plaza. They had slowed her
> fall, but—
>
> She was surrounded by cold, and white. She must have fallen into snow.
> She had no breath left in her.

And again makes it clear that the cats saved her by waking her, not through any special magic of their own.

> At that moment, though, she lay half-conscious, battered and bruised and about to freeze to death in the snow. It would be so easy, she thought, to drift off to sleep, and maybe to sleep forever.
>
> Something kept her from falling into that final sleep. There were noises, animal noises. The sound of cats.
>
> Miss Kitty?
>
> But it was far more than one cat. From all the meows and purrs that surrounded her, she must be in the middle of an army of cats, as if the whole feline population of Gotham City had come to her rescue.
>
> That was awfully nice of them. She had always liked cats. Now, if they would only calm down so she could get some sleep.
>
> But the cats wouldn’t leave her alone. Miss Kitty climbed upon her chest and breathed into her mouth. A Siamese purred meaningfully into her ear. Other cats rubbed against her legs and feet.
>
> An old tom bit her finger.
>
> Her eyes flew open.
>
> And she understood. She was Selina Kyle no more. She was reborn.

Answer (score 1):

I have not watched *Batman Returns* but if it is like *Catwoman*; Patience (the Catwoman incarnation of this movie) died and cats make her alive again.

It is told by the old woman (who is slightly implied to be Selina Kyle) that cats have magical powers and revived her from the dead and gave her abilities.

Comment: If the (implied) theory is that the old woman is Selina; then it's possible for her to come up with the explanation of magical cats _because she woke up next to cats_. I.e. cats aren't actually magical, but Selina believes that they are. Because she doesn't realize that she would have woken up regardless of any cat being present.

Answer (score 0):

Of course cats have magic!

It's funny, I saw Catwoman before this one and thought the 'licked back to life by magic cats' thing was the stupidest thing in a hilariously bad movie. Turns out *that* was the one thing she had in common with the actual Catwoman from the Batman movies? Mind: blown! XD

However, someone (I can't find it now) pointed out that Selina hit several things on the way down and so never fell constantly for an unsurvivable distance, and that she wasn't immediately skilled, struggling a lot at first. Maybe she wasn't 100% dead and brought back to life with superpowers by magical cats after all, but just had a personality shift via head injury like Phineas Gage.

Comment: Any source to support this answer?

Comment: You seem to assume that the cats must invariably have been the cause of Selina's resurrection. Why can't it just be a coincidence, i.e. Selina would have woken up regardless of any cats' presence?

Comment: I never really took it we were supposed to be sure the cats "licked her back to life". Her fall was broken by several awnings on the way down which in Hollywood physics is enough to survive the fall, then she woke up with the cats around her and attributed her survival to them.

Answer (score -2):

She doesn't die in Batman Returns. Nothing in the film expresses her death, which would have been a plot hole in and of itself seeing as there are no other cat magic resurrections happening anywhere else in the entire history of DC characters. Nothing about the entire movie is Paranormal in any sort of way. Hokey and unrealistic, yes, but not paranormal.

The cats play the same role for her as batman's bats did. Just the thing they needed at the time they decided to become vigilantes. An icon to fear and or respect.